# BottomNavigationView items background

Tags: android, android-studio

I have BottomNavigationView and I made a custom background for its items. It works, but not exactly as I expected: it has [wrong text and icon background colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBqYV.png)

XML for BottomNavigationView:

```
    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
            app:itemBackground="@drawable/bottom_nav_item"
            android:background="@color/bg_dark_gray"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
```

XML for item selector:

```
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item
            android:state_checked="true"
            android:drawable="@color/button_main_green_unpressed" />
        <item
            android:drawable="@color/bg_dark_gray"/>
    </selector>
```

How do I fix this? I want it to be the same color as the background.

[Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bgp8.png)

Comment: Can you add an image that shows your desired output?

Comment: @afhamu sure! I've added what I expect to see. The only problem is this weird gray background of the text and the icon.

Comment: @afhamu Can you please share the values of bg_dark_gray and button_main_green_unpressed. I would like to see if there is any transparency in these colors.

Comment: @NavjotSinghBedi you're right, there is no transparency for these colors. ```<color name="bg_dark_gray">#2c2c2c</color>``` ```<color name="button_main_green_unpressed">#00a97f</color>``` What do I have to change?